# Jquery validation multiple tabs, validate one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tabs, jquery-validate

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to use it and the validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to create a multi-part form with multiple tabs for different sections. Right now I have it where there are multiple tabs and the "Next" button switches to the next tab.

The problem I'm having is that when I finally submit on the last page, the form validates properly but if there are errors on the other page the user isn't notified, and validation really only happens once "submit" is clicked.

How would I validate each  individually when I click "Next"? I don't really want to create multiple forms or keep track of hidden fields :S Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //....stuff
    //tabs
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".nexttab").click(function() {
        //var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        //$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
    });

    //use link to submit form instead of button
    $("a[id=submit]").click( function(){
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
    });

    //form validation
    var validator = $("#myForm").validate();    
});
</script>

<form class="cmxform" id="myForm" method="post" action="">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#general">General</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2"></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="general">
             ....stuff...
            <p>
                <a class="nexttab navbutton" href="#tab2"><span>Next</span></a>  
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
            <h2>Tab2</h2>
            <p>
                <a class="nexttab navbutton" href="#general"><span>Prev</span></a>
                <a class="submit navbutton" id="submit" href="#"><span>Submit</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit:

@Andrew:

I did some combination of your 2nd example and disabling tabs. Seems to work, aside from having the page refresh re-disable the tabs.

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({

    disabled: [1,2,3,4,5],

    select: function(event, ui) {
        var valid = true;
        var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
        var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");

        if(ui.index > current)
        {
            $(panelId).find("input").each(function() {
                //console.log(valid);

                if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            });

        }

        return valid;
    }   

});
```

In combination with:

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("enable", selected+1);
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is possible using the [`.element(selector)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element) function of `validator`. What you're going to do is iterate through each element on the active tab and call that function on the input. This will trigger validation on each element in turn, showing the validation message.

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var valid = true;
    var i = 0;
    var $inputs = $(this).closest("div").find("input");

    $inputs.each(function() {
        if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
    }
});
```

Additionally, you'll probably want to run similar code when a user clicks a tab to go to a new set of inputs, instead of clicking "next".

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c2y6r/

**Update:** Here's another way you could do it, canceling the `select` event upon invalid form elements:

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate();
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var valid = true;
        var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
        var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");

        $(panelId).find("input").each(function() {
            console.log(valid);
            if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
                valid = false;
            }
        });

        return valid;
    }
});
```

However, now you have to consider allowing the user to go back when they've entered invalid data into the current page. On the other hand, you get the bonus of keeping all the validation code inside of one function which gets fired if the person clicks a tab or your next link.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c2y6r/1/

**Update 2**, if you want to allow people to navigate backwards through the tab interface:

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var valid = true;
        var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
        var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");

        if (ui.index > current) {

            $(panelId).find("input").each(function() {
                console.log(valid);
                if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            });
        }

        return valid;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks mate! The second method would be good except for the problem you mentioned. Perhaps there's a way of finding the order of the tabs and if the id thats clicked is less than/before the current tab, then return true anyway.

I'm probably going to go with the first way and then originally disable tabs to the right until it's accessed for the first time. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: @Jordan: You could always determine if the index being navigated to is less than the current tab index (for method 2, I'll update the example). However in either case you also have to think about the interaction that occurs when a user clicks from one tab to another and skips over some tabs that contain required fields. What happens in this case? Maybe you should only allow users to go forward one tab at a time.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to prevent the user from initially jumping to another tab, but I don't mind them jumping to tabs once they've already reached/unlocked the tab. Would example #2 do that? The other thing to consider is if people refresh the page or something. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jordan: Almost. The second update will only let you go backwards. You could pretty easily expand it to allow people to go to tabs `<=` to the highest numbered tab by keeping track of the highest tab index that the user has navigated to.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thanks for the answer. It's working fine only for `input` tags. Can you update your answer to work with `selection (dropdown)` and `checkbox` too?

Answer (score 0):

The existing code didn't work for me (maybe it's dated) so i came up with the following. This example is assuming using jquery tabs and jquery validator.

```
$('#tabs').tabs(
{
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui )
    {   
        var valid = $("#myForm").valid();
        if (!valid) {
            validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel are you using this plugin [link](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)