# how to validate the tabs data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery. I am facng one problem. Iwant to validate the tabs data. Make sure user have select the checkbox from each tab i.e in image there are three tabs like (Fitness, wellbeing and Nutrition) so user have to select atleast one checkbox from each tab

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/fitness') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
<div id="parentHorizontalTab">
    <ul class="resp-tabs-list hor_1 custom-tab-vertical">
        @foreach($fitnessdata as $allfitness)
        <li class="new">{{ $allfitness['name'] }}</li>
        @endforeach
        <!-- <div class="submit show-div">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Your Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control getdata" placeholder="Enter Own Category">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info addCategory">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="add-more">
        <h6>OR</h6>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add More</button>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="add-more">
            <h6>OR</h6>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-more-show">Add</button>
        </div> -->
    </ul>
    <div class="resp-tabs-container hor_1 custom-vertical-tabs">
        @foreach($fitnessdata as $key=>$allfitness)
        <div>
            <p>
                <div class="ChildVerticalTab_1">
                    <ul class="resp-tabs-list ver_1 custom-tab-horizontal">
                       <li>Top Services</li>
                       <li>Popular Services</li>
                       <li>Choose Own Services</li>
                       <li>Special Offers</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="resp-tabs-container ver_1 custom-horizontal-tabs">
                        <div>
                            <div class="list-services">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($allfitness['fitness'] as $topservices)
                                    @if($topservices['type'] == 1)
                                    <li>
                                        <label>
                                           <input name="{{ $allfitness['name']}}[]" value="{{ $topservices['name']}}" type="checkbox"> 
                                           <span class="services-name">{{ $topservices['name']}}</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="total-number">
                             <h6>Total Services Selected</h6>
                             <span class="badge">0</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="list-services">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($allfitness['fitness'] as $popular)
                                    @if($popular['type'] == 2)
                                    <li>
                                        <label>
                                            <input name="{{ $allfitness['name']}}[]" value="{{ $popular['name']}}"type="checkbox">
                                            <span class="services-name"> {{ $popular['name']}}</span> 
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="total-number">
                                <h6>Total Services Selected</h6>
                                <span class="badge">0</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <div class="name-contain-id-<?php echo $key+1; ?>">
                              <div class="name-list">
                                <input type="text" name="{{ $allfitness['name']}}[]" class="form-control" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="sign-btn signup-page">
                                <a id="name-contain-id-<?php echo $key+1; ?>" class="btn btn-info sign-bttn">Add More</a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- <div class="list-services_add">
                                <div class="btn-save-class">
                                    <input type="text" name="{{ $allfitness['name']}}[]" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="add-more">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-show">Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                            <!-- <div class="total-number">
                                <h6>Total Services Selected</h6>
                                <span class="badge">2</span>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="list-services">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($allfitness['fitness'] as $special)
                                    @if($special['type'] == 3)
                                    <li>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox"> 
                                                <span name="{{ $allfitness['name']}}[]" value="{{ $special['name']}}"class="services-name">{{ $special['name'] }}</span> 
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="total-number">
                                <h6>Total Services Selected</h6>
                                <span class="badge">0</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="btn-save-class">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save and Coutinue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far?

Comment: [StackOverfllow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643500/jquery-validation-multiple-tabs-validate-one-at-a-time) This will Help You.

Comment: i don;'t know how to validate the tabs data . anyone can write code for me. :(