# Validate all required data fields on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, data-annotations

I am using bootstrap tabs and use the data annotations to include the required. However it does not validate all the fields, I need it to validate the required, and if it is not validated, it selects this tab. I tried to locate the fields, but it only finds the ones of the selected tab.

I tried this code below, but it also did not work:

```
    $('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).find('input[aria-required=true]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert('O campo ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' é obrigatório!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I was able to solve this way

```
$('#FornecedorNovo').on('submit', function (e) {
  $.each($('input[data-required="true"]'),function(){
    if(!this.value || this.value == ''){
      $(this).css('border','red 1px solid');
      alert('Preencha os campos corretamente!');
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This might be [helpful](https://formden.com/blog/validate-contact-form-jquery)

Comment: It was not, as I need it to validate all fields of the tab, not just the selected one, and this is what is happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643500/jquery-validation-multiple-tabs-validate-one-at-a-time